# Unexpected crashes in android app spinner and orientation change

Tags: android, spinner, screen-orientation

To preface this question, this is my first app and I have a very basic understanding of android apps.

My first problem is the issue with screen orientation change. I've seen this question asked on here a million times, but I don't really understand the answers and I'm not sure if it is the same situation or not. My app crashes when the screen orientation changes. I am not using ViewFlipper as a lot of the questions mention. My app also crashes when you try to scroll through the options in a spinner. The spinner is populated correctly, and you can open it and select an option, but scrolling or opening it and changing selection multiple times causes a crash. I think my biggest problem here is I am not used to the Eclipse IDE or java (I am a .net developer primarily) and I feel like it leaves me completely in the dark when it crashes. All it ever says is "Source not found". That doesn't help me much.

So I guess my question is: does anyone know what would cause the application to crash in either of these two instances and/or how do I go about debugging the issues when it simply says "source not found"?

Comment: Should your code and exception in detail

Comment: @ArpitGarg what code do you want to see? There shouldn't even be any of my code executing at that point. It crashes when the screen is rotated. and as I said, I don't really get an exception, it says "source not found" and I don't know how to see the exception, that's part of my question.

Comment: Have you seen the LogCat output? If not open up DDMS and paste the logs here. In Android when the screen is rotated, the screen is recreated, unless you handle it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issues. Sort of anyways.

The spinner crash was caused by a null value in the array I was binding as the source. So that one was my fault.

The orientation crash was caused by... I'm not really sure. But to investigate I inserted `android:configChanges="orientation"` into the manifest to be able to handle the `onConfigurationChanged` event. I inserted the code to override the method and the problem stopped completely.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

That is the code necessary to fix the problem in it's entirety. I have no idea what was causing the problem or why that fixed it so if anyone can shed some light please comment!